# ServiceStack Validation Not Always Firing

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

So I was trying to build a End To End integration testing suite with RavenDB and ServiceStack but I ran into a really weird issue where the validation doesn't run on some requests. This is really strange and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using NCrunch. Sometimes the test passes, sometimes it fails.

Hope this is an easy fix and something bone headed I'm doing.

You can download the whole project on http://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/endtoend

You don't need anything other than VS2012 and NuGet Package Restore enabled.

**UPDATE: I decided to run this in both NCrunch and Resharper Test Runner and both give the same result [see image below].**

**UPDATE UPDATE: I thought it could be XUnit, so I tried to use NUnit. Nope still the same problem.**

[image: Test Run from NCrunch and Resharper]

**Another Update: Put in console writes as per user1901853's request. This was the result."

[image: Test Run 2]

**Latest Update: the RequestFilters are getting wiped out and I'm not sure why. It seems like it could be a threading issue, but I can't see where.**

My AppHost is using AppHostListenerBase.

```
    using EndToEnd.Core;
    using Funq;
    using Raven.Client;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Validation;
    using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

    namespace EndToEnd
    {
        public class TestAppHost
            : AppHostHttpListenerBase
        {
            private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

            public TestAppHost(IDocumentStore documentStore)
                : base("Test AppHost Api", typeof(TestAppHost).Assembly)
            {
                _documentStore = documentStore;
            }

            public override void Configure(Container container)
            {
                ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

                // Register RavenDB things
                container.Register(_documentStore);
                container.Register(c =>
                {
                    var db = c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>();
                    return db.OpenSession();
                }).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

                Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
                container.RegisterValidators(typeof(CreateWidgetValidator).Assembly);

                // todo: register all of your plugins here
                AuthConfig.Start(this, container);
            }
        }
    }
```

My base test class for all of my tests looks like this:

```
    using Raven.Client;
    using Raven.Client.Indexes;
    using Raven.Tests.Helpers;
    using ServiceStack.Authentication.RavenDb;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth;

    namespace EndToEnd
    {
        public abstract class ServiceStackTestBase
            : RavenTestBase
        {
            protected IDocumentStore DocumentStore { get; set; }
            protected TestAppHost Host { get; set; }
            protected JsonServiceClient Client { get; set; }

            protected const string ListeningOn = "http://localhost:1337/";

            protected string Username { get { return "testuser"; } }
            protected string Password { get { return "password"; } }

            protected ServiceStackTestBase()
            {
                DocumentStore = NewDocumentStore();
                IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(ServiceStackTestBase).Assembly, DocumentStore);
                IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(RavenUserAuthRepository).Assembly, DocumentStore);

                Host = new TestAppHost(DocumentStore);
                Host.Init();
                Host.Start(ListeningOn);

                Client = new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn)
                {
                    AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true,
                    UserName = Username,
                    Password = Password
                };

                RegisterUser();

                WaitForIndexing(DocumentStore);
            }

            private void RegisterUser()
            {
                Client.Send(new Registration
                {
                    UserName = Username,
                    Password = Password,
                    DisplayName = "Test User",
                    Email = "test@test.com",
                    FirstName = "test",
                    LastName = "user"
                });
            }

            public override void Dispose()
            {
                DocumentStore.Dispose();
                Host.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

my test class looks like this:

```
    using System;
    using EndToEnd.Core;
    using FluentAssertions;
    using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth;
    using Xunit;

    namespace EndToEnd
    {
        public class RegistrationTests
            : ServiceStackTestBase
        {
            [Fact]
            public void Throws_validation_exception_when_bad_widget()
            {
                var validator = Host.Container.Resolve<IValidator<CreateWidget>>();
                validator.Should().NotBeNull();


                try
                {
                    var response = Client.Post(new CreateWidget
                    {
                        Name = null
                    });
                    // It get's here every once in a while
                    throw new Exception("Should Not Get Here!");
                }
                catch (WebServiceException wex)
                {
                    wex.StatusCode.Should().Be(400);
                    wex.ErrorMessage.Should().Be("'Name' should not be empty.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My code looks like this for the service:

```
    using System;
    using Raven.Client;
    using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
    using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel;

    namespace EndToEnd.Core
    {
        [Authenticate]
        public class WidgetsService
            : Service
        {
            private readonly IDocumentSession _session;

            public WidgetsService(IDocumentSession session)
            {
                _session = session;
            }

            public CreateWidgetResponse Post(CreateWidget input)
            {
                var widget = new Widget { Name = input.Name };
                _session.Store(widget);
                _session.SaveChanges();

                return new CreateWidgetResponse { Widget = widget };
            }
        }

        [Route("/widgets", "POST")]
        public class CreateWidget : IReturn<CreateWidgetResponse>
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class CreateWidgetResponse
        {
            public CreateWidgetResponse()
            {
                ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
            }

            public Widget Widget { get; set; }
            public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }   
        }

        public class Widget
        {
            public Widget()
            {
                Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            }

            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
        }

        public class CreateWidgetValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateWidget>
        {
            public CreateWidgetValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(m => m.Name).NotEmpty();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cloned your repo, can replicate exactly what you stated. A trying to find some pattern. Have you tried enabling logging? I wonder if the POST request are getting cached, because when your `Throws_validation_exception_when_bad_widget` runs first, it passes. When it runs after either of the other two it fails.

Comment: That could make sense, is there a way to turn off caching?

Comment: actually just double checked, and I don't register a caching provider, and I remember that the request filter gets cleared "sometimes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have the ability to duplicate your environment but while running in VS2010, using .NET 4, NUnit and ReSharper Test Runner I have not been able to reproduce your issue of 'Validation not firing'. I have run your tests 30+ times. A couple of reasons I can think of Validation not firing would be not having the plugin added or the plugin not registering the validation filters. The 2 `if statements` below might give you some 'introspection' if either of the cases I listed are the issue. Hope this is somewhat helpful.

```
if (!TestAppHost.Instance.Plugins.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(ValidationFeature)))
{
    Console.Write("Validation Plugin is not added");
    //TestAppHost.Instance.Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
}

if (!TestAppHost.Instance.RequestFilters.Any(x => x.Target.ToString() == "ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Validation.ValidationFilters"))
{
    Console.Write("No validation request filter");
   //TestAppHost.Instance.Container.RegisterValidators(typeof(CreateWidgetValidator).Assembly);
}
```

Below is my packages.config so you can see the differences in our environments.

```
<packages>
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Client" version="2.0.2261" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Database" version="2.0.2261" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Embedded" version="2.0.2261" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="RavenDB.Tests.Helpers" version="2.0.2261" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Authentication.RavenDB" version="3.9.35" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="3.9.39" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.38" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
  <package id="xunit" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Comment: That's the strange part. The validation fires sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't fire. If I run the test alone, everything works everytime. It is when I run it in conjunction with other tests is when it fails.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce while running in conjunction with all the tests (30+ times). The 2 if statements (in answer) above may help diagnose why the validation is failing.

Comment: Tried your additions to my code and got the output of "No validation request filter.". Now why isn't there one? https://www.evernote.com/shard/s15/sh/9ad633bb-48d7-42b7-a98c-a211759580a4/d3384efb951c73c12803860be564beae

Comment: hmm - I guess it's progress. If the Validation plugin fails to load it should write a message to the Output window (using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine) with 'Error loading plugin " + exception. Anything there?

Comment: Well that's the weird part right. It loads sometimes and other times it doesn't. There really is no exception there. I wonder if there is something "Static" in ServiceStack that I am unaware of. I modeled my code after the integration tests found in the original source for the project.

Comment: If the plugin fails to load, the Exception would be 'swallowed silently' and only write to the log. I really don't know ServiceStack's internals well enough to debug the infrastructure. HttpListenerBase.Init() HttpListenerBase.Start() and EndpontHost.AfterInit() are methods/areas I have been looking over.

Comment: I checked this as the answer cause no one else replied. There was no solution found.

Comment: FYI, I did set up VS 2012 & NCrunch to test this and was able to reproduce your issue. However, I could not reproduce the issue when 'running with debugger' in NCrunch. Seems like an issue with ServiceStack and the NCrunch 'test runner'. Also, I was not able to reproduce using Test Explorer.

Comment: I don't think it is NCrunch, because I was able to reproduce it with ReSharper's test runner with XUnit and NUnit.

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh can you check it with the latest ServiceStack version? We modified ValidationFeature: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f0548148359613fa4af1a53ffbaa999c0240796b#L1R24 
We noticed the same problem and mostly it was related to static variables and context reusing by unit test runners. That fix should resolve that problem.

Comment: @desunit I upgraded to the latest version of ServiceStack on NuGet and still seeing the same issue. What version is your commit included in? I upgraded to 3.9.42.

Comment: I mean try to build it from the trunk and add reference to it.

Comment: I pulled down the latest code from ServiceStack on github, and built the ServiceStack.ServiceInterfaces project and looks like it is good now. Thanks so much, but I guess I have to wait for the next release cycle. Thanks @desunit.

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh - I was just experiencing the same thing. Thanks for posting the question. I am not going totally mad :-)