# ServiceStack and FluentValidation NOT firing

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I must be overlooking something around getting the **fluent-validation** to fire within basic **Service-Stack** application I created.
I have been following the example found [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation). For the life of me I can't seem to get my validators fire???? 
Crumbs, there must be something stupid that I'm missing....???

> I'm issuing a user request against the User-Service (http://my.service/users), the request goes straight through without invoking the appropriate validator registered.

Request is :
   {"Name":"","Company":"Co","Age":10,"Count":110,"Address":"123 brown str."}

Response :
   "user saved..."

---

Here is the code :
**1.DTO**

```
[Route("/users")]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**2.Validator**

```
 public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(r => r.Age).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

**3.AppHostBase**

```
public class ValidationAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public ValidationAppHost()
        : base("Validation Test", typeof(UserService).Assembly)
    {

    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

        //This method scans the assembly for validators
        container.RegisterValidators(typeof(UserValidator).Assembly);
    }
}
```

**4.Service**

```
 public class UserService : Service
{
    public object Any(User user)
    {
        return "user saved...";
    }
}
```

**5.Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ValidationAppHost().Init();
    }
```

Comment: Nothing stands out. How are you Posting your request? Does adding the format (http://my.service/users?format=json) to the end change the Response?

Comment: I'm just using the Google Chrome App. [REST-Console](http://codeinchaos.com/post/3610180596/rest-console-a-google-chrome-rest-http-client). I'm firing the JSON against my localhost instance of a standard ASP.NET web-site.

Comment: hmm... Copied your code and using REST Console settings 'Target > Request URI' = localhost/users, 'Target > Request Method' = POST,  'Body > Content Type' = application/json, 'Body > RAW BODy' = {your request above} and clicking 'Send' the validation fired. Are all other fields is REST-Console empty (ie Request Parameters)? Also see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297745/servicestack-validation-not-always-firing/15345117#15345117 for checking if Plugins/Filters are correctly setup.

Comment: Hey Paaschpa: Yes, my REST-Console settings are the same as yours, added similar code to what was indicated in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297745/servicestack-validation-not-always-firing/15345117#15345117)...Plugin collection is populated with ValidationFeature and one Filter is registered : `base {System.MulticastDelegate} = {Method = {Void RequestFilter(ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpRequest, ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IHttpResponse, System.Object)}}` Does this look correct?

Answer (score 8):

Ok....found the issue....I (in error) installed (via nuget) and referenced within my project the FluentValidation.dll with Service-Stack's FluentValidation implementation (see namespace `ServiceStack.FluentValidation`).
Once I removed this the sole incorrect FluentValidation reference and ensured that my validator extended from the service-stack implementation of the `AbstractValidator` the validators fired correctly...